# the code execution cannot proceed because python310.dll was not found

Tags: cython

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe -mconsole -DSIZEOF_VOID_P=8 -DMS_WIN64 hello.c -IC:\Users\sonke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -LC:\Users\sonke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs -lpython310 -o test.exe"  this is the command to compile cython to exe, but when i run test.exe on another machine it gives the error "the code execution cannot proceed because python310.dll was not found". Is there any way to fix it?

I'm so tired of this problem

Comment: Just to make sure: do you understand what a DLL is?

Comment: Cython isn't really a solution for making truly standalone executables. As soon as you fix your DLL issue, you'll find that it also depends on some of the Python standard library being available and on any module that you import being available. Use a tool that's designed for this problem instead

Answer (score 0):

That happens because to run that .exe requires Python 3.10 and easiest solution would be to install it and add to PATH. Or unzip portable version in the same folder.

Answer (score -1):

Hey u can download that dll file from here : [https://www.dll-files.com/python310.dll.html#:~:text=In%20the%20vast%20majority%20of,the%20game%2Fapplication%20installation%20folder](https://www.dll-files.com/python310.dll.html#:%7E:text=In%20the%20vast%20majority%20of,the%20game%2Fapplication%20installation%20folder).